# How to solve no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, cors, access-control

**CORS:**
A very common issue that most of the developers face when they hit a rest service from another domain and so do I.

I get this error :

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.**

Below is the jsp snippet.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>AJAX JSON SAMPLE</title>
<script type="application/javascript"> 
function load() 
{ 
   var url = "https://samplewebapp1.herokuapp.com/rest/json/get";//use any url that have json data 
   var request; 
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){   
    request=new XMLHttpRequest();//for Chrome, mozilla etc 
   }   
   else if(window.ActiveXObject){   
    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for IE only 
   }   
   request.onreadystatechange  = function(){ 
      if (request.readyState == 4  ) 
      { 
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);//JSON.parse() returns JSON object 
        document.getElementById("appName").innerHTML =  jsonObj.appName; 
        document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = jsonObj.language; 
      } 
   } 
    request.open("GET", url, true); 
 request.send();  
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 appName:
 <span id="appName"></span>
 <br /> language:
 <span id="language"></span>
 <br />
 <button type="button" onclick="load()">Load Information</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is the rest service implementation of that service.

```
`package com.heroku.rest;
 import java.util.Date;
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

 import com.heroku.model.Heroku;

 @Path("/json")
 public class HerokuRestService {

 @GET
 @Path("/get")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Heroku getTrackInJSON() {
         return new Heroku("My First Heroku", "Java", new Date().toString());
    }    }`
```

What am i missing.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a XmlHttpRequest to some other domain. You could simply use CORS to tell your browser to allow it. (It's completely browser specific due to some security reasons).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US use this extension to  allow access to no 'access-control-allow-origin' header request.

Or, you could manually configure CORS as well. Like described here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: That's the thing i dont want to do anything with the browser. How will the  other end users know about such an issue. 
Anyway i'll look into it that html5rocks.
But if there's any alternate approach which can be done in code and not with the browser please let me know.

Comment: In that case you could manually setup CORS but again I would rather suggest making your service serve the data irrespective of who the client is can be an app or a browser anything so you could return response with headers that allow Access control origin. Something like this, Response.ok()
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With").build();